Using a stream of unknown length for PutObject
I have the following code.
This works totally fine for normal file uploads. However, when using it with Streams, I get this:

Are you using a Stream of unknown length as the Body of a PutObject request? Consider using Upload instead from @aws-sdk/lib-storage.

I tried 10000 different ways to use lib-storage, and didn't manage to figure it out.
What's the minimum amount of changes so that this works for Streams of unknown length?

import { S3Client, HeadObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

// ...

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: 'ap-southeast-2',
  defaultProvider
})

// ...


class Files extends AuditMixin {
  async _uploadToAmazon (path, body) {
    const params = {
      Bucket: vars.config.amazonBucket,
      Key: path
    }

    let found = 0
    try {
      await s3.send(new HeadObjectCommand(params))
      found = 1
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name === 'NotFound') found = 0
    }

    if (found) {
      console.log('****************Skipped! ', path)
      return { key: path }
    } else {
      console.log('I would upload', path)
      try {
        const response = await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand({ ...params, Body: body }))
        return response
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading to Amazon S3:', error)
        throw error
      }
    }
  }

A possible "solution" is to do this, bit it feels really terrible:
import cs from 'convert-stream'
// ...

        if (typeof body.pipe === 'function') {
          body = await cs.toBuffer(body)
        }
        const response = await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand({ ...params, Body: body }))


Surely...?

Where is the code for your attempt to use lib-storage and how did it fail? Also see if the Uploading to AWS S3 as a stream example helps.
